# Getting a serializable collator instance

Tags: java, serialization, instance, collator

I can't seem to be able to serialize a TreeMap if I need to use a collator. There's really no info about it online and I can't seem to fix it by myself. Any help would be appreciated on how to get a Serializable Collator. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain a bit more why you want to serialize a collator - what do you hope to achieve by that? Depending on what you need it for, it might be easier to just serialize a Locale key or some enum value for choosing a collation strategy. The collator as a whole can be quite a complicated object with lots of rules etc. Just to be sure - we are talking about instances of [`java.text.Collator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/text/Collator.html)?

Comment: No, it does not answer it, as I've tried it and it didn't work. And I don't want to specifically serialize a collator, but I use it as a comparator in a TreeMap that I do want to serialize, and I don't see anyway to do that without it being serialized aswell.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need to do.

1. Implement a serializable collator class using the wrapper technique given in the answer to [Serializing Collator instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8346036/serializing-collator-instance).  (What this is doing is holding the actual collator in a `transient`  field, and *reconstructing* it by calling `Collator.getInstance` when the wrapper is deserialized.)
2. Create an instance of that class.
3. Instantiate the `TreeMap` class passing the collator instance as the constructor argument.

You should now be able to serialize the `TreeMap`.

Note that the `TreeMap` comparator is held in a `private` field that is NOT marked as `transient`, and it is being serialized / deserialized by the map's `private` `writeObject` and `readObject` methods.  There is no clean way to override this behavior in `TreeMap`.

The only other alternatives are to look for (or create) an implementation of tree maps where the comparator is marked as transient, or an implementation of `Collator` that is serializable.

---

Referring to the above link, you said:

> I've tried it and it didn't work.

It should work.  Perhaps you can tell us how it didn't work.  Did you get exceptions?  Incorrect behavior?

Comment: Oh man thanks, that was it, apparently I was using it wrong. Thanks for shedding some light on it!